# Is there any np.select alternative in pyspark Pandas API

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pyspark

I know that numpy.where and numpy.select function is really fast for dataframe processing. But now im using pyspark with Pandas API so it can be multi node processing. is there any alternatives for using numpy select without changing the dataframe into pandas or pyspark, but using pyspark Pandas API? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with pyspark.pandas api, I think it has limited usability. Some peculiar operations will require pure pyspark. Anyways, you can use the below if the amount of data being dealt with is manageable:

```
arrayed=ps_df[['sal','imp']].to_numpy()
arrayed[:,0][arrayed[:,1] == "sa"] = 1
```

The first line moves two pyspark pandas coluumns 'sal' and 'imp' to numpy array. In the second line, we modify the first column of array based on value of second column.